# Javascript libraries for typeahead / autocomplete in textarea, any recommendation?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, textarea

can anyone recommend a Javascript library to support typeahead in textarea?

- It should only perform autocomplete when trigger character like @ is 
  entered.
- Once match is found it should REMOVE the trigger character.
- Angular support is ideal, other frameworks are also considered

I found some typeahead examples on the web but none of them seem to match my criteria. Does anyone have any idea or does such library actually exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question [mentio](http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/) for angular does this job quite well